# Which configuration file for apache2 VirtualHost?

Tags: apache2

I have a VPS and I'd like to associate two domains to the VPS in different directories. I read I shall configure in Apache some `VirtualHost` tags in some configuration file. Which configuration file is that? Where it is stored in my ubuntu machine?

The folder tree I have for Apache is this:

```
/etc/apache2/
|-- apache2.conf
|       `--  ports.conf
|-- mods-enabled
|       |-- *.load
|       `-- *.conf
|-- conf-enabled
|       `-- *.conf
|-- sites-enabled
|       `-- *.conf
|-- sites-available
|       `-- *.conf
```

Is it in `sites-enabled/` or `sites-available/`? In which file? My version is `Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)`

Comment: Back in my day people used to say RTFM, its probably now considered rude but realy, put some effort before asking questions ;)

Comment: @EvilTorbalan  I'm newby on apache. The characters you spent on the comment, could have been used on reply.

Comment: Ask yourself why you have -4 on the question? I could have answered but people diving into tech/it need to first learn to read basic documentation, search google before asking questions. What you expect is someone to digest everything for you and bring it on a plate. And that's just the very beginning, things will get more complicated from now on. What are you gonna do, ask a question for every step? You clould have opened the files on those dirs to see whats inside, there is a default virtualhost in one of them ;) Seriously, try little harder ;)

Comment: I don't want to be expert in apache. If read the full documentation of all sw i deal with, i just read. Thanks anyway for the "tips"

Comment: well, then just use google, the answer is in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```